# String Grouping from a single column in Oracle database having million rows and removing duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle11g

We have a huge table and one of the column contains queries like e.g. in row 1
1. (((firstname:Adam OR firstname:Neil ) AND  lastname:Lee) ) AND category:"Legal" AND type:Individual
and in row 2 of same column
2. (((firstname:Adam* OR firstname:Neil ) AND  lastname:Lee) ) AND category:"Legal" AND type:Organization

Similarly there are few other types of Query strings which are used eventually to query external services.

Issue is based on certain criteria I have to group and remove duplicates from this table.

There are few rules to determine grouping of Strings in different rows.One of them is that if first name and lastname are same then ignore category and type values, therefore above two rows will be grouped to one. There are around million rows. Comparing Strings and doing grouping is not looking elegant solution. What could be best possible solution using sql.

Comment: This is not a site for advising.  It is a site for answering technical questions.

Comment: Hey Gordon, I have corrected that. Let  me know if question is not clear.

Comment: I can't think of an exact solution, but could you use a combination of REGEXP functions, to find characters such as wildcards for matching?
I've recently written about some Oracle functions [such as SUBSTR](http://www.completeitprofessional.com/oracle-substr/) but I don't know if that will be more complicated than using REGEXP.

Comment: Yes, I am using REGEXP only to group. However as there are many rules for grouping. Is temp table a good idea for applying these transformations?